# how to apply two list in ng-options based on ng-if in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am using two combo box.coming to first one,In that what I am select based on that I need to apply second combo box options.So I need to apply two different list in data-ng-options. Eg: in fisrt combo having two options like country names.and second one is states.If I select first combo as India then choose India states in second combo.If I select pakisthan in first combo then need to show pakisthan states in second combo etc.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this.

```
 <select  data-ng-model="statename" data-ng-if="country!=2"
                        data-ng-options="state.ID as state.Name for state in indiasStates"> </select>
<select data-ng-model="statename" data-ng-if="country==2"
                        data-ng-options="state.ID as state.Name for state in pakistanStates"> </select>
```

Comment: Good luck with this solution when you need to support 100 different countries.

Comment: for my functionality it is Ok. Because I don't have that much options in my functionality.But If you have any idea on that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the first select box, you need something like

```
ng-model="selectedCountry" 
ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries"
```

And in the second one, something like

```
ng-model="selectedState" 
ng-options="state as state.name for state in selectedCountry.states"
```

ng-if is completely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with condition

`ng-options='item for item in (selectedName === "India"? ["KA", "KL", "TN"]: ["AB", "BC"])`